# Subspace of Inner product space is an Inner product space

Tags: inner-products

How do I prove that a subspace $ M $ of Inner product space $V$ is an inner product space?
Isn't it obvious that the inner product of any two vectors from $M$ satisfies axioms? Does it require a formal proof?

Comment: Simply restrict the inner product to the subspace, all axioms are still satisfied.

Comment: Since the inner product on the subspace is just the restriction of the inner product on the whole space, there's nothing to prove.

Comment: I think the only thing worth proving in this case is that a subset of $\;V\;$ is *actually* a subspace.

Comment: I'd say it's more or less clear that each of the axioms still holds for the restriction.

That said, (for good reasons) sometimes authors allow inner products to be indefinite (but still nondegenerate), and it is no longer true that the restriction of the inner product to a subspace of the underlying vector space is still an inner product. (For example, the bilinear form given by polarizing the quadratic form $Q(x, y) := xy$ on $\Bbb R^2$ is nondegenerate, but its restriction to the $x$-axis is the zero bilinear form.) Meditating on this might illuminate the given problem some.

Comment: @Travis  you mean not every subspace of an inner product space is an inner product space?

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, that depends on what your definition of an inner product space is, and in particular whether you allow your inner product to be indefinite (but still nondegenerate).